# Spock testing framework Unroll all tests to the parent class , when using EmbeddedSpecRunner and display in test execution report

Tags: testing, report, spock, unroll

I am using EmbeddedSpecRunner to iteratively call tests from within a test . Though it runs successfully, I am not able to get each of the tests that were executed in the final Unroll. Only the parent test results are shown (Using a threadlocal to set each of the iterative itemized list for the next class to execute)

## Parent class

```
class RiskSpecTabsTests()
@Unroll
    def "executeTabsTests specName=#specName, tabName=#tabName"(String specName, String tabName) {
        given:
        when:
        List<String> failures
        CustomThreadLocalClass.setSpecTestProperty("currentTestTab", tabName)
        CustomThreadLocalClass.setSpecTestProperty("specName", specName)

            CustomThreadLocalClass.setSpecTestProperty("tables", [["WF_NEW_ADJ1"]
                                                                   , ["WF_NEW_ADJ2"]]);

        }

        EmbeddedSpecRunner specRunner = new EmbeddedSpecRunner()
        specRunner.throwFailure = false
        result = specRunner.runClass(RiskSpecTabTablesTest)

        failures = result.failures.collect { it.exception.getMessage() }
        log.error(failures)
        then:
        verifyAll {
            result.failures.size() == 0
        }
        where:`
        [specName, tabName] << tabs`
```

#Second Class

```
class RiskSpecTabTablesTest (String table){
    @Unroll
    def "executeTests for table=#table" (String table) {
        given:
        EmbeddedSpecRunner specRunner = new EmbeddedSpecRunner();
        specRunner.throwFailure = false

        when:
            log.info("Executing Test for table {}.", table)
            CustomThreadLocalClass.setSpecTestProperty("currentTable", table)
            TestExecutionSummary result = specRunner.runClass(RiskSpecTabTableTest)

        then:
        verifyAll {
            result.failures.size() == 0
        }
        where:
        [table] << CustomThreadLocalClass.getSpecTestProperty("tables")

    }
```

#Third class
RiskSpecTabTableTest

```
  @Unroll
    def "execute tab table testId=#testId " (Integer testId, String sample, Map<String, String> inputMap) {
        given:

        
        when:

        def result = command.executeCommand(tableName, executionContext, new HashMap<>(), tabStep.resultType)
        Object expectedResult = SpecTestTableHelper.getExpectedResultValue(inputMap)

        then:
        verifyAll() {
            expectedResult == result
        }
        where:
        [testId, sample, inputMap]  <<  new RiskSingleTableTest(this, getSpecificationContext(),
            CustomThreadLocalClass.getSpecTestProperty("specName"),
            CustomThreadLocalClass.getSpecTestProperty("currentTestTab"),
            CustomThreadLocalClass.getSpecTestProperty("currentTable"))
        
    }
```

If I run each of the individual test classes (RiskSpecTabTablesTest , RiskSpecTabTableTest), I am able to see each of the tests being executed as a result of the parameters passed under the "where" . The same behavior for RiskSpecTabsTests (the main class)

Is there a way to propagate all the unrolled tests to the parent class, in order to be able to view the report for each of the individual tests executed under the parent class execution, and not only the parent class tests.?

I tried toggling throwFailure on the specRunner , unroll annotation on the different classes . I am able to see the failures of child classes in the parent class via
`result.failures.collect { it.exception.getMessage() }`
but how can I make it visible via the Spock reports.
Thanks!

Comment: `EmbeddedSpecRunner`  is not designed to be used in the way you do, and as you noticed the test results will not be reported as part of the outer execution.